# Change background color of a row of Divs on hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, hover

I am trying to change the background color of a row of Divs on hover but I cannot figure out how to do that.

```
// row 1
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>

// row 2
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
// row 3
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

How do I hover on a row and highlight that rows Divs by changing their background color?
(My Divs are inside a css grid).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: How are you differentiating each row in the html? Have you researched [CSS hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)?

Comment: As an aside your commenting is invalid; html comments are of the form: `<!-- row 1 -->`, and there are no single-line comments (to the best of my knowledge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the background color upon hover for all divs like this in your css file:

```
.div {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.div:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Now the div will become yellow upon hovering.

If you want to make it specific for each row. You can wrap a row in a another div and give it an id. Then reference the ID in your css for the specific styling.

Your HTML:

```html
// row 1
<div id="first-row">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Your CSS:

```
#first-row {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
#first-row:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a hover pseudo style for the divs like

```
div:hover { background-color: #0000ff; }
```

If you need to differentiate the rows, please extend your class style with a row class or something specific

```
.row-1 div:hover { background-color: #0000ff; }
.row-2 div:hover { background-color: #00ff00; }
.row-3 div:hover {  background-color: #ff0000; }
```

Comment: 1. I added display: flex to get the divs to spread across horizontally but they don't.
2. I added the hover code per your help but when I hover the mouse, nothing changes color-wise.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
 </head>
<style>
.row-1 div:hover {background-color: #ff7dff;}
.flex9 {display: flex;}
</style>
 <body>
  <div class='row-1 flex9'>11111111</div>
  <div class='row-1 flex9'>22222222</div>
  <div class='row-1 flex9'>33333333</div>
  <div class='row-1 flex9'>44444444</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This div:

```
.element {
    background-color: #fe0101;
}
```

This div with mouseover:

```
.element:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).